# Matrix in a cell and calling values of this matrix

Tags: microsoft-excel, array

I would like to be able to create an matrix in a cell without referring to other cells.

Let's say in A1 I'd have the matrix

```
2 3 4
1 2 3
```

with entering something like ={2,3,4;1,2,3} in A1.

I would like then to be able to pick the values in other cells by doing something like A1 (1,2) and it would give me the value in first row second column so "2".

Is that possible? If not can we at least do it with an array?

Thank yoou

Comment: Why do you want a matrix in a single cell? Why not multiple cells within the worksheet, or even stored as a constant?

Comment: This is what named ranges are for.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the array each number in a cell starting from A1=2,B1=3 C1=4 First Row and A2=1, B2=2, C2=3 then in A4 Row and B4 Column in C4 Array Element for example:
A5=1, B5=2 in C5=`Offset($A$1,A5-1,B5-1)` you will have "3" which is first Row second Column

Answer (score 0):

Place your data in **A1** without the **=** and without the braces:

[image]

run this short macro:

```
Sub SetupCells()
    Dim ary, bry, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim a, b

    ary = Split([A1], ";")
    i = 1
    j = 1

    For Each a In ary
        bry = Split(a, ",")
        For Each b In bry
            Cells(i, j) = b
            j = j + 1
        Next b
        j = 1
        i = i + 1
    Next a
End Sub
```

to produce:

[image]